# Integer checking system in my Text Based game doesn't work

Tags: python, text

So I made a system for my game so that I can check whether the player's input is an integer. But for some reason, even if I put in an integer, it returns "Please enter integer." I believe it has something to do with this function right here, that's purpose is to check the players input and whether or not it is an integer:

```
def pII(options):
    #PII stands for Player Input Int 
    playerInput = (input("==> "))

    while playerInput != range(1, options):
        print("Please enter an integer")
        playerInput = (input("==>"))  

    while playerInput <= 0 or playerInput > options:
        print("This is not an available option")
        playerInput = int(input("==>"))    

    return(playerInput)
```

The logic makes sense to me, So I don't understand why it doesn't work. I don't get any errors, so at least that's that. Anyways, here's the complete code to my game if that helps. The code segement i took is from lines 15-27

```
#Made by Nick Pope--------------------------------------------------#
import sys
import os
import time
import random

os.system("mode con: cols=45 lines=80")
#Functions----------------------------------------------------------#
def save():
    print("                   This is supposed to save, but it doesn't work yet")

def clear():
    os.system('cls')

def pII(options):
    #PII stands for Player Input Int 
    playerInput = (input("==> "))

    while playerInput != range(1, options):
        print("Please enter an integer")
        playerInput = (input("==>"))  

    while playerInput <= 0 or playerInput > options:
        print("This is not an available option")
        playerInput = int(input("==>"))    

    return(playerInput)
#Graphics-----------------------------------------------------------#
  #All Graphic functions start with "g" so that i don't take any 
  #names I might need later
def gLine():
    #Function Draws lines 
    ps2("******************************************************************************************************************")

def gHeader():
    gLine()
    ps2(""" 
___________.__              __      __               __  .__             _____  __________      .__                 
\__    ___/|  |__   ____   /  \    /  \___________ _/  |_|  |__    _____/ ____\ \____    /____  |  |   ____   ____  
  |    |   |  |  \_/ __ \  \   \/\/   |_  __ \__  \\   __\  |  \   /  _ \   __\    /     /\__  \ |  |  / ___\ /  _ \ 
  |    |   |   Y  \  ___/   \        / |  | \// __ \|  | |   Y  \ (  <_> )  |     /     /_ / __ \|  |_/ /_/  >  <_> )
  |____|   |___|  /\___  >   \__/\  /  |__|  (____  /__| |___|  /  \____/|__|    /_______ (____  /____|___  / \____/ 
                \/     \/         \/              \/          \/                         \/    \/    /_____/         """)
    gLine() 

def gExit():
    clear()
    save()
    gLine()
    ps2("""
___________      .__  __  .__                                     
\_   _____/__  __|__|/  |_|__| ____    ____                       
 |    __)_\  \/  /  \   __\  |/    \  / ___\                      
 |        \>    <|  ||  | |  |   |  \/ /_/  >                     
/_______  /__/\_ \__||__| |__|___|  /\___  / /\ /\ /\ /\ /\ /\ /\ 
        \/      \/                \//_____/  \/ \/ \/ \/ \/ \/ \/""")
    gLine()
    sys.exit

def gHelp():
    gLine()
    p2("""
  ___ ___        .__              _____                       
 /   |   \  ____ |  | ______     /     \   ____   ____  __ __ 
/    ~    \/ __ \|  | \____ \   /  \ /  \_/ __ \ /    \|  |  \
\    Y    |  ___/|  |_|  |_> > /    Y    \  ___/|   |  \  |  /
 \___|_  / \___  >____/   __/  \____|__  /\___  >___|  /____/ 
       \/      \/     |__|             \/     \/     \/    """)
    gLine()
    print("Welcome to the help menu!")
    ps("I will write this later")
#Text Functions-----------------------------------------------------#

def ps(str):
    #This function allows the game to type like a real person 
    #PS is short for "Print Slow"
    typing_speed = 50
    count = 0
    space = True
    #This aspect of the function works with the autotext wrap
    #To make sure that it only wraps after full words, not 
    #midway through 
    for letter in str:
        if letter == " ":
            space == True
        else:
            space == False

        count += 1
        sys.stdout.write(letter)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(random.random()*10.0/typing_speed)
        #The 3 lines after this function as an autotext wrap.
        if count == 100 and space == True:
            print('\n')
            count = 0
    print('')

def ps2(str):
    #This function is the same as PS1 but without the Text Wrapping 
    typing_speed = 200
    for letter in str:
        sys.stdout.write(letter)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(random.random()*10.0/typing_speed)
    print('')
#Player Data--------------------------------------------------------#
pName = "Yorick"
playerInput = 0
#Mechanics----------------------------------------------------------#

#Game Loop----------------------------------------------------------#

def titleScreen():
    gHeader()
    ps("1. Start")
    ps("2. Load")
    ps("3. Exit")
    ps("4. Help")
    options = 4

    pII(options)

    if pII == 1:
        start0()
    if pII == 2:
        load
    if PII == 3:
        gExit()
    if PII == 4:
        gHelp()

def start0():
    clear()
    ps("Your name my child..what do the mortals use to summon you?")
    pName = str(input("==>"))
    ps(pName +"?" " I amused by the creativity of the lower realms. The void..she calls to you, she favors you, just as her divinity does to me. You..shall be my avatar. It is time. Her prophecy shall be fullfilled. Awaken, my child!")






titleScreen()
```

Comment: How does `while playerInput != range(1, options)` make sense? Did you mean `while playerInput not in range(1, options)`?

Comment: So I tried that, but it didn't change the outcome at all. != makes sense to me in the sense that it's "While the player input is not equal to range of 1, to the amount of options." It's just supposed to be another way of handling the selection of choices

Comment: No. Equality operator has a very specific meaning and that is, well, being equal. You should be using the `in`/`not in` operators. If that didn't resolve your issue you might have other errors.

Comment: I'll think of it as that for no on. I tried what you said, and it didn't fix it. It didn't hurt it either though. I haven't found the source of the error though.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is from  testing if the option is correct with `playerInput != range(1, options)`. This always returns true as playerInput is never a range. The comparison should be:

```
playerInput not in range(1, options)
```

which compares *playerInput* to each value in the range

Remember that we also want to take the input as an integer, so the class becomes :

```
def pII(options):
    #PII stands for Player Input Int 
    playerInput = (input("==> "))

    while playerInput not in  range(0,options):
        print("Please enter an integer")
        playerInput = int(input("==>"))  

    while playerInput <= 0 or playerInput > options:
        print("This is not an available option")
        playerInput = int(input("==>"))    

    return(playerInput)
```

Comment: @seluk actually just commented this. I switched out the line, but the same error still persists. I guess there is another error in my code, but I haven't found it yet. Odd

Comment: @TyronePope you're correct, I didn't actually test the new code. There is also an issue where the input is not getting casted to integer, making our comparison in the while loop never evaluate to false. I have changed the code now